# how to update shopping cart quantity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

how to update shopping cart quantity , i developed cartview page and when make update to all items,it take old value of quantity (binded) from textbox not new that i written it in textbox .

[image]

shopping cart code

```
 public void SetItemQuantity(int productId, int quantity)
        {
            // If we are setting the quantity to 0, remove the item entirely
            if (quantity == 0)
            {
                RemoveItem(productId);
                return;
            }

            // Find the item and update the quantity
            CartItem updatedItem = new CartItem(productId);

            foreach (CartItem item in Items)
            {
                if (item.Equals(updatedItem))
                {
                    item.Quantity = quantity;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

full shopping cart

```html
<asp:ListView ID="FullCartListView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProductID" OnDataBound="FullCartListView_DataBound" OnItemCommand="FullCartListView_ItemCommand">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
               <table class="table-bordered table table-cart">
        <thead>
          <tr>
       <th>
           No items in shopping cart .
       </th>
          </tr>
           
        </thead>
                                
                           </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="cart-product">
              <%--<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="remove" data-original-title="Remove">&times;</a>--%>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="RemoveLB" data-toggle="tooltip" CssClass="remove" data-original-title="Remove" runat="server" CommandName="Remove" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID")%>'>
                                    &times;
                                </asp:LinkButton>
              <a href="ProductDetails.aspx?ProductID=<%# Eval("ProductID") %>" title="" class="product-cart">
                <img src="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ProductsHTMLPath"].ToString() %><%# Eval("PictureName") %>" width="72" height="100" alt="">
                <h3 class="product-title"><%# Eval("Name") %></h3>
              </a>
            </td>

           <%-- <td>
              <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" class="edit-link" data-original-title="Edit">
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
              </a>
            </td>--%>

            <td><span class="amount"><%# Eval("Price") %> </span></td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="QuantityTextBox" CssClass="qty" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("quantity") %>' />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ProductIDLabel" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' Visible="false" />
                <%-- <br /><br /><asp:Button ID="UpdateCartButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-dark btn-outline" CommandName="Update" CommandArgument="<%# Eval("ProductID") %>" Text="Update"></asp:Button>--%>
            </td>
            <td><span class="amount">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="SubTotalPriceLabel" Text='<%# (decimal)Eval("quantity") * (decimal)Eval("Price") %>' />

                </span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" class="table-bordered table table-cart">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <%--<th style="width:10%"></th>--%>
            <th style="width:10%">Unit</th>
            <th style="width:10%">QTY</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Subtotal</th>
          </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
        </thead>
                 <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
              <div class="text-right">
                <%--<a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-outline">Empty cart</a>--%>
                  <asp:Button ID="EmptyCartButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-dark btn-outline" Text="Empty cart" OnClick="EmptyCartButton_Click"></asp:Button>
                 <asp:Button ID="UpdateCartButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Update cart" OnClick="UpdateCartButton_Click"></asp:Button>
                <%--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update cart</button>--%>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
                </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

code behind of update quantity

```html
  protected void UpdateCartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < FullCartListView.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                
                TextBox quantity = (TextBox)FullCartListView.Items[i].FindControl("QuantityTextBox");
                Label productid = (Label)FullCartListView.Items[i].FindControl("ProductIDLabel");
                ShoppingCart.ShoppingCart.Instance.SetItemQuantity(Convert.ToInt32(productid.Text), Convert.ToInt32(quantity.Text));

            }

            
            BindData();

        }
                                                             
   protected void BindData()
        {
            FullCartListView.DataSource = ShoppingCart.ShoppingCart.Instance.Items;
            FullCartListView.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you're saying, I think the text boxes are being bound on postback, click events happen after postback, so if the controls are being databound on postback, the updates in the text box would be lost

Edit: More specifically the page load after a postback happens before event handlers are called

Edit2: looked closer at your code after your comment, you're using Eval on the textboxes which will not store your updates, try bind instead

Comment: i forgetten add this line .
thanks .

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData();
            }
        }

Comment: try #bind instead of #eval on the text boxes, eval can only read data, bind is two way read and write